# Wildcard search using SearchKick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, elasticsearch, searchkick

Is there any way to use wildcard after a word and before a word as mentioned below..

```
User.search "*" + "admi"+"*"
```

or any other solution to solve such problems using SearchKick gem.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it's not too late.

You want the keyword to be appeared in the middle of the text, right? You should use [Partial Matches](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#partial-matches) as your search option.

For example, in model User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick text_middle: [ :name ]
end
```

Searching:

```
User.search("admi", fields: [{name: :text_middle}]).each do |user|
  # Do something with user
end
```

If the search result is empty, try `User.reindex` before a search.